# Can't debug in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm new to VS Code, and is following [the official tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6cOsxaNC06c) to learn how to debug. However, it just won't work. First, the UI looks different. It shows **"RUN"**.

[image]

Compared to what the UI looks like in the video, which shows **"DEBUG"**.

[image]

Also, I added a breakpoint and hit the green start button, **it just never stops**.

Here's the `launch.json` file:
[image]

What should I do to make the debugger work?

Comment: UI is ok. Same as my VS Code UI. Can you check your VS Code explorer and open the folder again?

Comment: @GökselÖZER Tried close and reopen, same result.

Comment: Have you ``launch.json`` right? Check here the ``"program":`` is the path true?

Comment: I took a screenshot of it, please take a look. I didn't modify it.

Comment: In my json ``program`` is different: ``"program": "${workspaceFolder}\\test.js"``

Comment: I guess that's because I'm using Mac and you're using Windows.

Comment: Try starting node in command line using `node --inspect app.js`

Comment: @chiragrtr Thanks, I found out my node is broken somehow. Reinstalled and it can work. You can create an answer if you want.

Comment: This is super annoying in VS Code. In Visual Studio you just click the button and it works and stops at any break points you put in, it should work the same way in VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `node` in inspect mode.

In terminal / console, do:

```
node --inspect app.js
```